# what does the symbol <> means?

Tags: c++, templates

```
template <class T>
T Bucky<T>::bigger(){
  return (first>second?first:second);
}
```

Why we need to put the <> after Bucky before :: in the code above?

Answer (score 3):

The out of class definition of the function requires to specify the named qualifier of the class it belongs to.

Obviously `Bucky` is a template class:

```
 template<typename T>
 class Bucky {
     T bigger();
 };
```

The full qualifier is `Bucky<T>`, hence you have to specify that at the function definition.

---

To extend a bit: How should the compiler differentiate that from

```
 class Bucky {
 };
```

otherwise, which is a different class and valid to exist at the same time.